# Android RTP API level 8

Tags: android, rtp

I have to implement a camera sharing on Android in API level 8. 
I take the image data in YUV format and compress them to jpg. Now I have to send these images over the network. 
As this should be a live camera view, I wanted to use UDP packets to send the data. Sadly, these packages are too large to send. The other idea is to send these packets over RTP, now I'm facing the problem with RTP on Android.
I had found that the JMF supports RTP but it seems that there is no way to port JMF to android.

Is there anyone who can give me a hint how I could solve that problem?

Answer (score 0):

Now I have found a solution which works for me.
I used the KryoNet library to send the imagedata via UDP to the clients.
jLibRTP supports only packages smaller than 1,5kb what is too small for the images.

Maybe this helps someone.